# Where is Auth variable stored in laravel , and how to make changes in it

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I was wondering, where is the code to generate Auth variable or class whatever it is.  And how can I modify it.

Comment: What do you mean by `Auth variable`? Why you want to change it?

Comment: I actually want to add an attribute named number, so that I can use Auth::number()

Comment: This is unclear what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to add another field in database named `number`? And have a look in `AuthController` may be you can find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you should follow these directories  if you are looking for **Trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUser**

```
 vendor> framework> Foundation> Auth> AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers
```

you able to access in this way and you can change whatever you want

Comment: Yahh Ohk.. I actually found out many of the files like the above mentioned, but couldn't find the Auth...

Comment: which one you looking for or what are you looking for ? I do not understand, you able fo find if you follow directiories.

Comment: Sir, actually,  instead of using the login form provided,  in my website I just want the user to create account using his mobile number so,. As in the usual authentication,  it's possible to access the users name using Auth::User()->name., so I want to make changes with this mentioned Auth, so that I can access my user using Auth::User()->number

Answer (score 0):

firstly, You should add new column named number in user table

```
User(Model)

protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','number'
    ];  

 AuthController

    protected function create(array $data)
            {
                return User::create([
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'number => $data['number'],    
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                ]);
            }
```

afterwards, you able to access in this way **Auth::user()->number**

Comment: Sir,  if I want to remove username,and password from the login form what should I do?

Comment: do you want to login with email instead username?